# Unknown host 'No such host is known (Hoàng-H?)'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU2d7.png)

I am having trouble cloning a project on gitlab.

I tried setting automatic proxy in settings but it still doesn't work.

Please give me a solution .

```
    debug {
        def host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName()
        buildConfigField "String", "LOCAL_IP", "\"" + host + "\""
        testCoverageEnabled = true
    }
```

Build failed with an exception at line: def host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName()

Comment: Please do not post images of code or debugging messages. Copy the text from your terminal output and place it within code blocks in your question.